# Orbeon fr:relevant missing from fields used in a reusable component upon submit

Tags: forms, orbeon

I'm using Orbeon v 2018.1.
I have a simple form which includes a reusable component.
The reusable component has a repeatable section with multiple grids and fields, and some of the fields have a visibility condition.

Upon submitting the form, all the fields have the *fr:relevant* attribute, except for the ones in the reusable component within the repeatable section.

Is this a known issue? Can this be solved in a different way?

I tried adding the attribute manually with the xf:insert, but it wasn't added.

```
<xf:insert
    event="xforms-disabled"
    context="."
    origin="xf:attribute('fr:relevant', 'false')"/>

<xf:delete
    event="xforms-enabled"
    ref=".//(@fr:relevant)"/>
```

Comment: By "reusable component" do you mean a [section template](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/section-templates), or something entirely custom?

Comment: For section templates, this is probably addressed by the fix for [#3829](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3829) in Orbeon Forms 2018.2.

Comment: Yes, exactly, a section template which incorporates a repeated section.
So this issue is known and has been resolved in version 2018.2?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!